# android setOnItemClickListener and onItemClick keeps giving me the same Toast

Tags: android, onitemclick

I'm trying to get the contact's CONTACT_ID, when their cell is clicked. Do you know how I can do this?

At present, Toast keeps giving me, no matter which cell in the list I click, '215', which is the CONTACT_ID of my first contact. Here's my code :

```
// Select item on listclick
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String usercontactid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), usercontactid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                      }

                 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `cursor.moveToPosition(i)` instead of `cursor.moveToFirst()`